# grep and sort using a pattern file

Tags: sorting, batch-file, cmd, grep

I have two txt files: patterns.txt and fulldb.txt

I want to output the lines of fulldb.txt which contains a line in patterns.txt so I do:

```
fgrep -f patterns.txt fulldb.txt > output.txt
```

This works.

But now I want to have the output sorted like in the order found in patterns.txt. I can do:

```
copy /y NUL output_sorted.txt > NUL
for /F "tokens=*" %%J in (patterns.txt) do (
    fgrep "%%J" fulldb.txt >> output_sorted.txt
)
```

But this takes too much time at runtime when the files are big enough.

Any better solution ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to run the full grep (your first code) generating an temp file and then the partial greps (the second code) against the temporary file instead of the fulldb?

Comment: @mikedu95 You have fgrep but do you have a shell there too? It's easier scripting with bash.

Comment: Thank you MC ND. This works better.

Comment: konsolebox I'm under Windows so I use cmd to script. Do You have a better solution using bash instead of cmd ? Because I can use bash too if it works better.

Answer (score 2):

i see you're on cmd, but you said in comments that a bash solution is fine by you,

the following would probably work:

`while read pat; do fgrep "${pat}" fulldb.txt >> output_sorted.txt; done < patterns.txt`